# pool updated payment is not normal

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

Here are my logs:

```
2017-01-11 16:35:11 Error with transfer RPC request to wallet daemon {"code":-4,"message":"Transaction would be too large.  try /transfer_split."}
2017-01-11 16:35:11 Payments failed to send to
```

What happened to the transaction?

Answer (score 4):

The transfer RPC call will by design try to create one transaction. If the transaction is too big to be included in a block, it will fail. This is what happened in your case, and is why the message tells you to use transfer_split instead, which can create several transactions for your transfer.

If you change the RPC from transfer to transfer_split, note that the return will not be a txid, but a list of txids. This has relevance when handling the return value, if you do so.